# How to count total number of nodes in sub tree from XML tree structure using DOM and JS?

Tags: xml, dom, tree

For a given node I need to find the total number of sub tree node to set the weight property of that given node.
I am wondering how can we recursively count total nodes in sub tree  from XML tree  structure using  DOM and JS and set the weight property of that node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function countNodes(node) {
  var i = 0, c = node.childNodes.length, result = c;
  for (; i<c; i++) result += countNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
  // if you want: node.weight = result;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @ZabedAkbar I have the sinking feeling that your problem was a homework question.

Comment: nope.. I am working on a project for tree api which will generate different tree layout. Thanks for your help btw.